# How to run the same SQL query for different schemas in PL/SQL loop

Tags: oracle, plsql

Suppose I have three schemas: `A`, `B` and `C`. According this Oracle documentation [Syntax for Schema Objects and Parts in SQL Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements009.htm) the general syntax for referring to an object is:

```
schema.object
```

for example:

```
hr.departments
```

where `hr` is schema (owner) and `departments` is object (ie. table).

I need to use different schema names in the SQL query inside PL/SQL block. In other words, **I need run exactly the same SQL query, but for different schemas (owners).**

I have following PL/SQL code so far:

```
set serveroutput on size unlimited
set head off
set feedback off
set echo off

DECLARE
    i_schema VARCHAR2(100);

BEGIN
  FOR r IN (SELECT username FROM dba_users where username in ('A', 'B', 'C') order by 1)
  LOOP
    i_schema := r.owner || '.' || 'TABLE_NAME';
    dbms_output.put_line(chr(10) || 'SCHEMA ===> ' || i_schema );
    FOR t IN (SELECT * FROM i_schema order by 2)
    LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line(RPAD(t.COLUMN1,75) || '|' || t.COLUMN2);
    END LOOP;
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

In the 14th line I tried also different notation:

```
FOR t IN (SELECT * FROM "r.username".TABLE_NAME ORDER BY 2)
```

but in the both cases I got below error:

```
PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Thanks in advance for any help received.

Comment: What actually is your requirement finally? Please elaborate. What you  to achive

Answer (score 1):

```
FOR r IN (SELECT username FROM dba_users where username in ('A', 'B', 'C') order by 1)
  LOOP
    i_schema := r.owner || '.' || 'TABLE_NAME';
    dbms_output.put_line(chr(10) || 'SCHEMA ===> ' || i_schema );
    FOR t IN (SELECT * FROM i_schema order by 2)
    LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line(RPAD(t.COLUMN1,75) || '|' || t.COLUMN2);
    END LOOP;
   END LOOP;
```

You cannot do that since **SQL** doesn't allow **dynamic table_name**, it must be **static**. In order to achieve the task, you need to (ab)use **EXECUTE IMMEDIATE** in your PL/SQL block.

Declare a string type variable, prepare the dynamic query and assign it to the string variable.

However, looking at what you are further doing, I don't see any reason to (ab)use **EXECUTE IMMEDIAT**E. Simple use a **REFCURSOR**.

But I see all this is pointless as you are anyway **hardcoding** the **schema name**, so what's the point in writing the **PL/SQL** code when you could do it in simply 3 SQL queries in **pure SQL**. It would hardly take less than a minute using a good **text editor** to **replace the schema name** in 3 SQLs.

Use **UNION ALL**:

```
SELECT RPAD(t.COLUMN1,75) || '|' || t.COLUMN2 FROM A.tablle_name t
UNION ALL
SELECT RPAD(t.COLUMN1,75) || '|' || t.COLUMN2 FROM B.tablle_name t
UNION ALL
SELECT RPAD(t.COLUMN1,75) || '|' || t.COLUMN2 FROM C.tablle_name t
```